# Writing an integer to a file with fputs()

Tags: c, file, integer

It's not possible to do something like `fputs(4, fptOut);` because fputs doesn't like integers. How can I work around this?

Doing `fputs("4", fptOut);` is not an option because I'm  working with a counter value.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What about

```
fprintf(fptOut, "%d", yourCounter); // yourCounter of type int in this case
```

Documentation of `fprintf` can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fprintf/).

Answer (score 6):

The provided answers are correct. However, if you're intent on using fputs, then you can convert your number to a string using sprintf first. Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){  
  uint32_t counter = 4;
  char buffer[16] = {0}; 
  FILE * fptOut = 0;

  /* ... code to open your file goes here ... */

  sprintf(buffer, "%d", counter);
  fputs(buffer, fptOut);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
fprintf(fptOut, "%d", counter);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know 6 years too late but if you really wanted to use `fputs`

```
char buf[12], *p = buf + 11;
*p = 0;
for (; n; n /= 10)
    *--p = n % 10 + '0';
fputs(p, fptOut);
```

Should also note this is for educational purpose, you should stick with `fprintf`.

Comment: [What is `48` for?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Codepage_layout)

Comment: @Andrew Henle 48 is the ASCII decimal code for the digit 0. This converts the digit to it's ASCII form. 48 is added to each digit internally when using `printf("%d")`

Comment: Why are you blindly assuming ASCII?  Didn't click on the link I provided, did you?

Comment: @Andrew Henle fixed. I was blindly assuming the reader should be able to understand this for what it is, rewriting the wheel. Using `fprintf("%d")` is of course preferred. The reader should also be able to tell that blindly using this code also destroys `n`.