# open() and write() functions in C

Tags: c, file-io, posix, system-calls

I'm trying to write in a .txt file the content of the variable `environ`.

```
int archivo = open(argv[1], "rw");
int i=0;
while(environ[i]!=NULL){
    write(archivo, environ[i], 1024);
    i++;
}
```

The file is created but no content is added. Does anyone know why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229377/writing-an-integer-to-a-file-with-fputs

Comment: You are confusing `open(const char *pathname, int flags)` and `fopen(const char *path, const char *mode)`

Comment: Yes, but the thing is i want to do it using the write command

Comment: How did you declare `environ`? And note that you tell `write` to always write 1024 bytes, no matter how long the string pointed to by `environ[i]` is. This is guaranteed to raise eyebrows.

Comment: Yes, but you're still confusing [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) and [`fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html). (Hint: Only one of these functions takes a string to define the open mode).

Comment: Added POSIX tag since these functions aren't standard C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. consult `man 2 open` to get the right arguments for `open`. It should be:

   ```
   open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
   ```
2. You should only write ad much as you actually have:

   ```
   write(archivo, environ[i], strlen(environ[i]));
   ```
3. You have to make sure that what you wrote actually left the buffer:

   ```
   size_t string_length = strlen(environ[i]);
   size_t wrote = 0;
   while (wrote < string_length) {
       size_t bytes_wrote = write(archivo, environ[i] + wrote, string_length - wrote);
       if (bytes_wrote >= 0)
           wrote += bytes_wrote;
       else {
           perror("write");
           abort();
       }
   }
   ```

   `write` does not guarantee that all that you submit will be written.

Ideally you should look for the far more programmer friendly `stdio` calls `fopen` and `fwrite`.

```
FILE * fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");

// loop i
if (!fwrite(environ[i], strlen(environ[i]), 1, fp)) {
    perror("fwrite");
    abort();
}
```

Comment: Actually, shouldn't that be `strlen(environ[i])+1` ? (Or else follow each write with a delimiter of some sort?)

Comment: @ElchononEdelson unless you are writing binary files it's a bad idea to write the null terminator out too. A delimiter wouldn't be a bad idea though :). Still this wasn't part of the question.

Comment: True it wasn't part of the question, but you still need one or the other.

Comment: you should retry `write` if `errno == EINTR`.

Comment: @SergeyL.: Appending a new-line however might make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've got to change your flags for opening a file.  "rw" isn't for open(), it is for fopen().

```
open(argv[1], O_WRONLY);
```

I think is the minimum required for writing to a file using open

EDIT: I found a link http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/open.html

Comment: Interesting.  Somehow google gave me an out of date link.  Thanks.