# How to insert variables on a .txt with fputs C

Tags: c, file, text

I wanna introduce info on a txt, and i have this:

```
int main(){

  FILE * file;

  file=fopen("viajes.txt", "w");
  char select;
  char dni[tm_dni];
  printf("Introduce DNI:\n");
  scanf("%s", dni);
  fputs("DNI cliente:", file);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing an integer to a file with fputs()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229377/writing-an-integer-to-a-file-with-fputs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
char textoACopiar[100];

strcpy(textoACopiar, "Este es tu DNI: ");
strcat(textoAcopiar, dni);
fprintf(file, "%s\n", textoACopiar);
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
fputs("DNI cliente:", file);
```

prints a static string to the file, which you then need to follow with the dynamic data:

```
fputs(dni, file);
```

You can also do:

```
fprintf(file, "DNI cliente: %s\n", dni);
```

You should of course also check that the various I/O calls (including `scanf()`) succeed.

Comment: `fputs()` doesn't add newlines. Only `puts()` does

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Oops, thanks, mis-read the manual page. Fixed, of course.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `#include <string.h>` and merge them and write in file

```
char res[100]="DNI cliente: ";
char dni[100]="something";
strcat(res,dni);
printf("%s",res);
```

> Ouptput: DNI cliente: something

Like This

```
char *result=malloc(strlen("DNI cliente: ")+strlen(dni)+1);
  strcpy(result, "DNI cliente: ");
  strcat(result, dni);
  printf("%s",result);
  fputs(result, file);
  fclose(file);
```